# Run chrome extension and submit data to PHP script on page load (automate the process)

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

I am first time using chrome extension for web crawling. I get data in HTML popup and then submits it to PHP script on button click. Now I want to do this functionality on page load. So on page load data will be collected and submit it to PHP script. I am using extension as below

menifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":     "Test Extension",
    "version":  "1.0",
    "offline_enabled": true,

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js":      ["jquery.min.js","content.js"],
         "run_at": "document_end"
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "file:///*",
        "downloads"
    ],

    "page_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, response) { 

    /* First, validate the message's structure */
    if (msg.from && (msg.from === "popup")
            && msg.subject && (msg.subject === "DOMInfo")) {
        /* Collect the necessary data 
         * (For your specific requirements `document.querySelectorAll(...)`
         *  should be equivalent to jquery's `$(...)`)*/


        var domInfo = {
            name : $('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(1) > br').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue.trim(),
            address : $('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(2) > br').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue.trim() + " "
                      + $('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(2) > br').get(1).nextSibling.nodeValue.trim(),
            reg_date : $('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(3) > br').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue.trim(),
            legal_form : $('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(4) > br').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue.trim()
        };
        /* Directly respond to the sender (popup), 
         * through the specified callback */
        response(domInfo);
    }
});
```

popup.js

```
/* Update the relevant fields with the new data */
function setDOMInfo(info) { 
 document.getElementById("name").value = info.name;
 document.getElementById("address").value = info.address;
 document.getElementById("reg_date").value = info.reg_date;
 document.getElementById("legal_form").value = info.legal_form;

}
/* Once the DOM is ready... */
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 //console.log("DOMContented...")
 /* ...query for the active tab... */
 chrome.tabs.query({
 active: true,
 currentWindow: true
 }, function(tabs) {
 /* ...and send a request for the DOM info... */
 chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
 tabs[0].id,
 { from: "popup", subject: "DOMInfo" },
 /* ...also specifying a callback to be called 
 * from the receiving end (content script) */
 setDOMInfo);
 });
});

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.getElementById('btn_php_call')
      .addEventListener('click', download);
  });

function download()
{   
    event.preventDefault();

    // The URL to POST our data to
    var postUrl = 'link to PHP script';

    // Set up an asynchronous AJAX POST request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', postUrl, true);

    // Prepare the data to be POSTed by URLEncoding each field's contents



    // Handle request state change events
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 

    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
    // Send the request and set status
    xhr.send($('#frm_info').serialize());
}
```

popup.html

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="frm_info">
    <h3 style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;"> DOM Info </h3>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="">
    <input type="text" name="reg_date" id="reg_date" value="">
    <input type="text" name="legal_form" id="legal_form" value="">
    <input type="button" id="btn_php_call" value="submit">
</form>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Currently I need to click on chrome extension then data renders in  popup.html and when I click on submit button then data goes to PHP. I want to do it on page load so user will no need to do it manually.

Edit :
I added image of chrome extension when I click on extension (T symbol). then it load information in popup. When I click on submit data in popup goes to PHP script

[image]

Comment: What is your question? What you've written so far looks more like a brief. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok. question is I want to get data from web page in html popup of chrome extension and submit it to PHP script. I want all this process on page load. Currently I have to manually click on chrome extension and manually click on submit button

Comment: Why down vote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the background page**

In your manifest, change your current `"background"` key with:

`"background": { "page" : "background.html", "persistent": true}`

and your `"content_scripts"` key with:

`"content_scripts": [{"matches":"the_URLs_you_want_to_scrape", "js" : ["content.js"], "run_at": "document_idle"}]`

This will be **background.html**:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id=myForm>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
      <input type="text" name="reg_date" id="reg_date">
      <input type="text" name="legal_form" id="legal_form">
    </form>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In your **background.js** file include this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
  if (message.from == "cs") {
    document.getElementById("name").value = message.name;
    document.getElementById("address").value = message.address;
    document.getElementById("reg_date").value = message.reg_date;
    document.getElementById("legal_form").value = message.legal_form;

    var encodedData = [].reduce.call(document.getElementById("myForm").elements, function(acc,cur){
      acc.push(cur.name+"="+encodeURIComponent(cur.value));return acc},[]).join("&");

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(){
      //check the response
    }
    xhr.open("POST",your_link_to_PHP_script);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(encodedData);
  }
});
```

Then your **content.js** will directly be:

```
var myMessage = {
  from: "cs",
  name : document.querySelector('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(1) > br').nextSibling.nodeValue.trim(),
  address : document.querySelector('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(2) > br').nextSibling.nodeValue.trim() + " "
                  + document.querySelectorAll('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(2) > br')[1].nextSibling.nodeValue.trim(),
  reg_date : document.querySelector('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(3) > br').nextSibling.nodeValue.trim(),
  legal_form : document.querySelector('ul.companyDetails li:nth-child(4) > br').nextSibling.nodeValue.trim()
};

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(myMessage);
```

Bonus: you don't need JQuery :)