# Auto execute chrome extension repeatedly

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

I am using chrome extension for web crawling where I insert text in text field and click on search button using below code

```
var id = 'some id say for eg 100';
$('#id').val(id); // It will set value 100 to search box in browser
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button"), // search button 
random = button[0]; 
random.click();
```

then it submits the form and goes to the details page of id(100) inserted in search textbox. On that page I use web crawl as mentioned in answer of [Run chrome extension and submit data to PHP script on page load (automate the process)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388140/run-chrome-extension-and-submit-data-to-php-script-on-page-load-automate-the-pr/47390700#47390700) in short data from details page in submitted to **PHP script using chrome extension**. now I want to come back again to previous page where I inserted search id for search. and search for next id say 200. so I will make an array of all ids I want to search and then one by one search information for those ids. Some thing like

```
var arr= [100,200,700,500];
for(var i=0; i< arr.length; i++)
{ 
   var id = arr[i];
   $('#id').val(id); // It will set value 100 to search box in browser
   var button = document.getElementsByClassName("button"), // search button 
   random = button[0];  
   random.click();
}
```

but I do not understand how I can come back to search page and keep track of ids

Comment: Capture the `POST` variables sent on the initial search page call. Store them using [the storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) and resend the request

Comment: I'd recommend doing a background load of the pages, rather than going to each of them.  For example, if each ID has a page Url of `http://someshop.com/products?id=100` then you could use an Ajax call for each of the IDs, scrape what you want and then you're done.  It will be a lot faster than lots of redirects.  You could even do this with a bookmarklet, which is a LOT less work than an extension.

Comment: @Archer  id is not part of URL

Comment: @WillParky93 I will try it

Comment: I did not say that id was part of the Url.  That was an example.  Please read my comment properly as I'm making suggestions that will help if you understand.

Comment: ok. Actually I am not much familiar with chrome extensions I will try it. but I can not skip click on search button to go next page as it not directly accessible

Comment: Thank you both of you. I achieved it using storage API and ajax call for each ID