# Access pagination links using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping

I am using chrome extension to crawl data from website. It runs on page load. Now I have situation where there is pagination on website as below

```
<p class="pageUpdate">
   <span class="currentPage">1</span>
   <a href="javascript:;" onclick="changePage('2');">2</a>
   <a href="javascript:;" onclick="changePage('3');">3</a>
   <a href="javascript:;" onclick="changePage('4');">4</a>
</p>
```

I want to visit all pages on pagination and read data using chrome extension. But I am not getting how I can go to next page.

I am using chrome extension as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388140/run-chrome-extension-and-submit-data-to-php-script-on-page-load-automate-the-pr/47390700#47390700)

Comment: have you tried triggering the click event on those links?

Comment: I think about it. But I am not getting how I can call changePage function from my code. I am using first time chrome extension. Not much expert in java script

Comment: That linked answer doesn't run the remote page's scripts so you'll have either to figure out the final URL yourself and construct it, or use a different approach - open that site in iframe or a tab, have a content script run there, send the click event, grab the results.